# How to remove white spaces in project's name while running on Apache Server

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created one java script web project , named "abc abcd def" , in eclipse helios 3.6, when i run it on Apache server , in eclipse browser , white spaces are replaced by "%20" or "_", Our team is building one custom browser , when i run this project to custom browser , then white spaces are not replaced , in source code , while passing the url I am replacing white spaces of selected project via ,getProjectName().replaceall(" ","") . But Custom Browser
says the "abc%20abcd%20def resource is not available".

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Apache's `alias` configurations, and/or create a `symlink` to your project.

Hope that helps